# codeigniter cms categories pagination issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am building a simple cms with codeigniter and i want to have pagination showing few posts per page from chosen category.
I am getting these errors:

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Vijesti::kategorija()

Filename: controllers/vijesti.php

Line Number: 12 

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: cat_name

Filename: controllers/vijesti.php

Line Number: 13

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\www\ci_cms_yt\system\core\Exceptions.php:185)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 688
```

model "vijest":

```
<?php
class Vijest extends CI_Model{

    function get_news_by_name($cat_name,$num=20,$start=0){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_cat_name=? ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $start,$num";
    $array=array($cat_name);
    $this->session->set_userdata('term',$cat_name);
    $query=$this->db->query($sql,$array);
    return $query->result_array();
    }
    function get_post($slug){
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE slug='$slug'");
    return $query->result_array();
    }
    function get_posts_count(){
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT post_id FROM posts");
    return $query->num_rows();
    }

}

?>
```

controller "vijesti":

```
<?php
class Vijesti extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('vijest');
    $this->load->model('home_model');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    }


    function kategorija($cat_name){
    $data['vijesti']=$this->vijest->get_news_by_name($cat_name,1,0);
    $data1['navigation']=$this->home_model->get_cats_nav();
    $data3['sidebar_news']=$this->home_model->sidebar_news();
            $config['base_url']=base_url().'vijesti/kategorija/';
    $config['total_rows']=$this->vijest->get_posts_count();
    $config['per_page']=1;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '&gt;';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="sr-only">(current)</span>';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pages']=$this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view('header',$data1);
    $this->load->view('vijesti_po_kategoriji',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer',$data3);

    }



    function vijest($slug){
    $data1['navigation']=$this->home_model->get_cats_nav();
    $data2['vijest']=$this->vijest->get_post($slug);
    $data3['sidebar_news']=$this->home_model->sidebar_news();
    $this->load->view('header',$data1);
    $this->load->view('vijest_pojedinacno',$data2);
    $this->load->view('footer',$data3);
    }
}

?>
```

view "header":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>News</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.js');?>"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/mojstil.css');?>">
</head>
<body>
<div class="sadrzaj">
    <div class="head">
    <a href="<?=base_url()?>home/index"><img id="logo" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/img/admalogo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbarr">
        <ul id="menuu">
        <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>home/index">Home</a></li>
        <?php
        foreach($navigation as $nav){
        ?>
        <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>vijesti/kategorija/<?=$nav['cat_title']?>"><?=$nav['cat_title']?></a></li>
        <?php

        }

        ?>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

view vijesti_po_kategoriji:

```
<div class="post_area">
    <?php
    foreach($vijesti as $row){
    ?>
    <h2><a class="ltitle" href="<?=base_url()?>vijesti/vijest/<?=$row['slug']?>"><?=$row['post_title']?></a></h2>
    <span><i>Author:</i>&nbsp;<b><?=$row['post_author']?></b>&nbsp; &nbsp;<b><?=$row['post_date']?></b></span>
    <img src="<?=base_url()?>news_images/<?=$row['post_image']?>" width="100" height="100" alt="title_image" />
    <div><?=substr($row['post_content'],0,300)?><a class="rmlink" href="<?=base_url()?>vijesti/vijest/<?=$row['slug']?>">Read more</a></div><br>
    <?php
    }
    echo $pages;
    ?>  

    </div>
```

view "footer":

```
<div class="sidebarr">
    <h4>Recent news</h4>
    <?php
    foreach($sidebar_news as $sn){
    ?>
    <div class="recent_posts" data-link="<?=base_url()?>vijesti/vijest/<?=$sn['slug']?>">
        <img src="<?=base_url()?>news_images/<?=$sn['post_image']?>" width="60" height="60" /><p><?=$sn['post_title']?></p>

    <div style='clear:both'></div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <h4>Subscribe</h4>
    <div class="pretplatite_se">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" id="pretplata">
    </div>
    <h4>Follow us</h4>
    <div class="pratite_nas">
    <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/img/facebook.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/img/twitter.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_area">
    Copyright &copy; <?php echo date("Y",time());?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If i put

```
$config['base_url']=base_url().'vijesti/kategorija/'.$cat_name;
```

it wont let me click through the pagination.Help anyone?

Comment: the error says all: $cat_name is not defined.

Comment: @Vickel defining $cat_name in the construct or in the kategorija method does not solve the missing argument error.Every time i go back through the pagination i get those errors  because somehow the argument for the kategorija method is lost

Comment: The problem is not for pagination.$cat_name is not defined when you first time hit that controller.what is the URL at your browser when you got that error?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam when i get errors i have http://localhost/ci_cms_yt/vijesti/kategorija/ in my URL

Comment: Your url is wrong.It should be  `localhost/ci_cms_yt/vijesti/kategorija/A_CATEGORY_NAME`. You missed category name.You receiving $cat_name at your controller function but your are not passing it.That's why it produce that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume when you first time click the page your url is like this

```
site_url/Vijesti/kategorija/a_category_name
```

If that is your URL Then your Kategorija function will look like this

```
function kategorija($cat_name){
  $data['vijesti']=$this->vijest->get_news_by_name($cat_name,1,0);
  $data1['navigation']=$this->home_model->get_cats_nav();
  $data3['sidebar_news']=$this->home_model->sidebar_news();
  $config['base_url']=base_url().'vijesti/kategorija/'.$cat_name;
  $config['uri_segment'] = 4;//you need to add this.At your case its 4 I think.
  //rest of the code
  $config['total_rows']=$this->vijest->get_posts_count();
}
```